# dictionary of dictionary key to multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested dictionary object i want to convert to multiindex data frame, how can I achieve it.

E.g.

```
t['a'] = dict()
t['b'] = dict()
t['a']['1'] = pd.DataFrame([ [1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0] ])
t['a']['2'] = pd.DataFrame([ [5.0,6.0],[7.0,8.0] ])
t['b']['1'] = pd.DataFrame([ [1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0] ])
t['b']['2'] = pd.DataFrame([ [5.0,6.0],[7.0,8.0] ])
```

so I want to convert to one data frame with index like

```
a
   1        0      1  
      0    1.0    2.0 
      1    3.0    4.0
   2  
      0    5.0    6.0
      1    7.0    8.0
b
   1
      0    1.0    2.0
      1    3.0    4.0
   2
      0    5.0    6.0
      1    7.0    8.0
```

I think I can use `MultiIndex(levels=[ ['a','b'], [1,2] ])` but I don't know how to construct labels. I also don't know how to pass in dict values as data array.

Answer (score 4):

I find it's easiest to get to a MultiIndex from a list of tuples, as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object).

Using your example, we have a nested dictionary like

```
In [25]: t
Out[25]: 
{'a': {'1':    0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4, '2':    0  1
0  5  6
1  7  8},
 'b': {'1':    0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4, '2':    0  1
0  5  6
1  7  8}}
```

If you want to make your head hurt a bit, you can use this list comprehension:

```
In [50]: tuples = [(x, y, z) for x in t for y in t[x] for z in t[x][y]]

In [51]: tuples
Out[51]: 
[('a', '1', 0),
 ('a', '1', 1),
 ('a', '2', 0),
 ('a', '2', 1),
 ('b', '1', 0),
 ('b', '1', 1),
 ('b', '2', 0),
 ('b', '2', 1)]
```

And then `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)` will work as your index.

Getting the values unpacked is a bit more work.

Edit: You really should just go to Jeff's answer, but for completeness:

```
In [114]: df = pd.concat([x for z in t for x in t[z].values()])

In [115]: df.index = idx

In [118]: df
Out[118]: 
       0  1
a 1 0  1  2
    1  3  4
  2 0  5  6
    1  7  8
b 1 0  1  2
    1  3  4
  2 0  5  6
    1  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

a dict of frames forms a panel, `to_frame` transmutes to a 2-level index,
you want an additional level which concat forms when passed a dict

In theory you could do something like a recursive reduction if you needed more levels, but that blows up the brain. To get your exact output, you can do a `sortlevel`.

```
In [36]: concat( dict([ (k,Panel(v).to_frame()) for k,v in t.items() ]) , names= ['level'])
Out[36]: 
                   1  2
level major minor      
a     0     0      1  5
            1      2  6
      1     0      3  7
            1      4  8
b     0     0      1  5
            1      2  6
      1     0      3  7
            1      4  8
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have 3 levels. I come up with this `pd.concat(dict([ (k,pd.concat(dict([ (x, pd.Panel(y).to_frame()) for x,y in v.items()]))  ) for k,v in t.items()])` but result looks wrong

Comment: the output above does have 3 levels named: level,major,minor. I believe that's what u asked

Comment: sory, I meant I only gave 2 levels (dictionary of dictionary) to illustrate the case. Your solution works great in that case. But in reality I have 3 levels dictionary. That is  `t['a'][1]['f']=pd.DataFrame(...)`. So I took your solution expanded one more level but my understanding is wrong because the result doesn't look correct.